# zmq / How to send response to different clients?

Tags: python, server, client, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to build a chatbot with zmq in Python. 
I already connected different clients to the server, when a client sends a message, it gets printed on his terminal, and on the terminal of the server, but not on the terminals of the other clients.

I only found ways to respond to the current clients, but not to everyone at the same time.

All of my chatclients look like this, with different names:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to chatbot...")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
name = "Max"

while True:

message = input("Message: ")
socket.send_pyobj({1:[name, message]})

#  Get the reply.
message2 = socket.recv_pyobj()
print("%s: %s" % (message2.get(1)[0], message2.get(1)[1]))
```

And my server looks like this:

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
#  Wait for next request from client
message = socket.recv_pyobj()
print("%s: %s" % (message.get(1)[0], message.get(1)[1]))
time.sleep(1)

#  Send reply back to client

socket.send_pyobj({1:[message.get(1)[0], message.get(1)[1]]})
```

Does someone know a way, that every client sees the messages of every other client as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the message to every client you use use zmq.PUB/zmq.SUB

If you want to keep you request reply pattern you will need to open another socket for the pubsub.

The server will bind zmq.PUB socket and send the messages on that.
The clients will connect a zmq.SUB socket then subscribe to all

```
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
```

You could also leverage the subscriptions further and allow each client only subscribe to conversations it is interested in.